# No elementKind for supplementary

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Anyone seen this kind of error?

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error: no elementKind for supplementary. Please file a bug on UICollectionView as this should not be possible.'[enter image description here][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTiEq.png

Comment: Do you have any supplementary views (header, footer)? Does your layout class expect there to be any?

Comment: That was it. i didn't provide a kind in my Layout when providing supplementary view

Answer (score 1):

When creating layout for header i forgot to give it a kind which causes the crash. So if anyone sees this error it might be  because you are creating a header with just size

I changed this

let header = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: headerSize)

to

let header = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: headerSize, elementKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, alignment: .top)

And it's all good